# Remove id3v2 tag c++

Tags: c++, windows, mp3, id3-tag, id3v2

Does anyone know how to, given an mp3 file, remove the id3v2 header from it in c++? I'm working on a windows machine and I can't find any instructions on how to get id3lib working on windows. Otherwise, I'd just use that.

Comment: For `id3lib`, all you do is download the binaries and headers and then include them into your project ([here is an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495765/c-library-include)), it shouldn't be that hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried reading the [id3v2 standard](http://www.id3.org/id3v2-00)? [This document](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) describes the structure of the id3v2 tag.

Comment: I had, but I missed the part where they describe the structure of the header, including the part where they tell you how big the tag is. So I should just be able to strip out the first x bytes from the file then...