# Errors while using headers in a visual studio 2010 custom actions project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, custom-action

I have a custom actions project in vs 2010 , in the source when i try to add the headers as:

```
#include "wx/wxprec.h"
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/string.h"
#include "wx/tokenzr.h"
```

and compile it , following errors encuntered:

```
 Error  12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall wxStringData::Free(void)" (?Free@wxStringData@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall wxStringData::Unlock(void)" (?Unlock@wxStringData@@QAEXXZ)    C:\MSIvalidate\Samples\Source Code\MSISerialValidateSample\MSISerialValidateSample\MSISerialValidateSample.obj  MSISerialValidateSample

Error   13  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\MSIvalidate\Samples\Source Code\MSISerialValidateSample\MSISerialValidateSample\Debug\MSISerialValidateSample.dll    MSISerialValidateSample
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the library that implements the headers to your project?

Comment: i tried adding :
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll in the linker options under additional library directories

Comment: You don't add the dll, usually there is a .lib file as well. You add that and the lib file will load the dll at run time. Also there's two steps, you add the directory where the library is under 'additional library directories' but you also have to add the name of the library itself somewhere else.

Comment: @jahhaji am adding msi.lib in the additional dependencies in linker options

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14667/discussion-between-linda-harrison-and-jahhaj)

Comment: Sorry. intended to answer, not comment.

Comment: Well, fooey. The software will not accept my answer. Says it is "trivial" and converts it to a comment.  [See an answer to the same question for a different DLL.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495765/c-library-include/2496142#2496142